# Detecting file changes in directory synced with external cloud storage in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, ubuntu-16.04, python-watchdog

I am making a software that detect if a new file is uploaded into the Google Cloud Platform's bucket storage from virtual machine instance. A file directory named images was mounted to the bucket using Cloud Storage Fuse by this command

```
gcsfuse cloud-storage-bucket ~/mystuff/images
```

Whenever a file is uploaded into the bucket storage, the file will also appear in the images directory. I am using Python Watchdog package to detect if a new file is created

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/bin/bash
import time
import TextDetector
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

DIR="~/mystuff/images"

class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event): # when file is created
        # do something, eg. call your function to process the image       
        print("Got event for file %s" % event.src_path)
        TextDetector.detect_text(event.src_path)

observer = Observer()
event_handler = ExampleHandler() # create event handler
# set observer to use created handler in directory
observer.schedule(event_handler, path=DIR)
observer.start()

# sleep until keyboard interrupt, then stop + rejoin the observer
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

The problem is the watchdog did not detect anything even when there is a new file created in the images directory every time I uploaded something in the bucket storage. I also tried using inotify but the result is also the same. The code runs without any problem when I tried locally in Windows platform. I am actually quite new to Ubuntu. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: were you able to figure the solution to you problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into the following options:

- [Cloud Pub/Sub Notifications for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) with [example in Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/notification_polling.py)
- [Cloud Functions Storage Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage)
- [Cloud Storage Object Change Notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification)

I would advise against building on top of FUSE connector and utilise native functionality provided by the platform.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am quite new to this platform so a lot of the functionality that I am still not familiar with. I will try to explore more of the options.